# Object rotates unexpectedly while following path

Tags: animation

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HVjzH.jpg here is my problem. I am trying to make this car go in a traight line, turn around, and come back. I have a path set up for this, but when I link it with the follow path constraint it starts rotating... strangely to say the least. I have tried moving the parent empty to the center of mass and that did not work, so thats off the books. can anyone help?

Comment: could you please share your file (at least the important objects): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: sure thing! https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1bsQX1jrxj9wNLWONxG-keWIxVqopgPC5

Comment: Hi. While videos can be good, ideally all question content should be in the question body, in the form of good descriptions of the issue and images. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to apply the scale of your curve, it squashes the scale of the empty and therefore of the car:

[image]

Comment: tysm!!!! this saved my ass!